# helmfile: run prepare/cleanup scripts before/after release install/uninstall

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I am using a helmfile to deploy a release, with postsync hook.
ex:

```
  hooks:
  - events: ["postsync"]
    showlogs: true
    command: "./create_namespace.sh"
    args: ['{{`{{.Release.Namespace}}`}}', '{{`{{ .Values.kubeContext}}`}}']
```

but the issue I am having now is that this hook executes after install and also after uninstall, what I want to achieve is this:

- after install run a script ex: `post_install.sh`
- after uninstall run a script ex: `cleanup.sh`

Comment: The Helmfile documentation doesn't suggest a hook that runs only after installation.  Can you add an ordinary Helm hook to the chart you're installing instead?